# How to get attribute it self in function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need get attribute name for selector another element
this is my html code

```js
//I've tried this but it does not work or maybe there is something wrong
/* $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnadd').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  });
}); */

function addval() {
  var btnini=$(this).attr("name");
  $("#txt"+btnini).show();
  $("#btn"+btnini).show();
  $(this).css("display","none");
}
```

```html
<!-- I've tried this but it does not work or maybe there is something wrong 
//<button type="button" id="btnadd" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button> -->

<input type="text" id="txt-opsional" style="display:none;" />
<button type="button" onClick="addval()" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-opsional" style="display:none;">simpan</button>
```

when i click button "tambahkan", textbox id="txt-opsional" and button id="btn-opsional" will show, so button "tambahkan" will hidden

I hope there is a better suggestion
Thank You

Comment: Try to pass this in onclick function as  onClick="addval(this)" and access this "this" as a function param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using inline event handler(not recommended, especially when jQuery is used), you need to pass a reference to the clicked element, you can do it by using `this` in the inline event handler like

```js
//I've tried this but it does not work or maybe there is something wrong
/* $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnadd').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  });
}); */

function addval(el) {
  var btnini = $(el).attr("name");
  $("#txt-" + btnini).show();//also need to add `-` to txt
  $("#btn-" + btnini).show();
  $(el).css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- I've tried this but it does not work or maybe there is something wrong 
//<button type="button" id="btnadd" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button> -->

<input type="text" id="txt-opsional" style="display:none;" />
<button type="button" onClick="addval(this)" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-opsional" style="display:none;">simpan</button>
```

---

Using jQuery handler

```js
//I've tried this but it does not work or maybe there is something wrong
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addval').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      btnini = $this.attr("name");
    $("#txt-" + btnini).show(); //also need to add `-` to txt
    $("#btn-" + btnini).show();
    $this.hide();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- I've tried this but it does not work or maybe there is something wrong 
//<button type="button" id="btnadd" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button> -->

<input type="text" id="txt-opsional" style="display:none;" />
<button type="button" class="addval" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-opsional" style="display:none;">simpan</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You left out the dash (`-`) in the selectors

```
function addval() {
  var btnini=$(this).attr("name");
  $("#txt-"+btnini).show();  // changed "#txt" to "#txt-"
  $("#btn-"+btnini).show();  // changed "#btn" to "#btn-"
  $(this).css("display","none");
}
```

And you'll need to send `this` to the `addVal` function

```
<button type="button" onClick="addval(this)" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```js
function addval($this) {
  var btnini = $this.attr("name");
  $("#txt-" + btnini).show();
  $("#btn-" + btnini).show();
  $this.css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt-opsional" style="display:none;" />
<button type="button" onClick="addval(this)" name="opsional">Tambahkan</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-opsional" style="display:none;">simpan</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function clickMe(button) {
  alert($(button).attr('name'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clickMe(this);" name="abc">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onClick="addval.apply(this)"  name="opsional">Tambahkan</button>
```

Bind `this` to addval()!

Make the addval's context be the button element.
In this way you needn't modify your `addval` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the onclick function at the button to `onClick="addval.apply(this)"` this will make the "this" variable inside the function to be the button object. And dont forget to append the "-" char at jQuery selector: `$("#txt-"` and `$("#btn-"`